# Repository isn't instantiated with @Autowired

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a null pointer exception for a JPA repository, I thought repositories didn't need to be instantiated when they have `@Autowired`.

```
@Component
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void createUser(User user) {
        System.out.println("user email = " + user.getEmail());
        repository.save(user);
    }
...
```

**Application**

```
@ComponentScan({"mypackage", "mypackage.service"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the repository code. 
Have you used the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation ?

Comment: is your `UserService` class annotated with `@Component` or something? did you enable competent scan on your app?

Comment: You need to annotate UserService class too so that it is going to be in spring container scope and so that the appropriate injected bean(s) can be injected. As mentioned by @shahaf

Comment: I annotated it with Service also have @ComponentScan("mypackage"), still not working

Comment: found why, it was because i was instantiating the service in the controller, i @autowired it and now it works

Answer (score 0):

@autowired is used to inject beans pre-instantiated by spring's container based on the applicationcontext.xml file so make sure to add the appropriate bean you would like to inject in that file.
[from spring's doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To1hK.png)

Answer (score 0):

This UserService class must to be used annotation (@Service / @AppService) instead of @Component.